# Custom react hook to for text field seems to be broken

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have been trying to come up with a custom hook to make the textfield configurable, i.e pass the set of data to a custom hook which would give me the text field that needs to be used.

The text field using the hook is being rendered as expected but I do not understand why this approach is breaking the input created using the custom hook. After every keystroke the input is losing focus and is not working as the other input that is using `useState` directly. It would be great if someone can explain what is going wrong and what I failed to understand.

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import useTextFieldBroken from "./useTextFieldBroken";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [notBrokenValue, notBrokenSetValue] = useState("");

  const [TextFieldBrokenInputOne] = useTextFieldBroken(
    "brokenOne",
    "Broken Input One",
    ""
  );

  const notBrokenOnChange = e => {
    notBrokenSetValue(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <label htmlFor="notBroken">
        <h3>Not Broken Input</h3>
        <input
          id="notBroken"
          onChange={notBrokenOnChange}
          value={notBrokenValue}
        />
      </label>
      <TextFieldBrokenInputOne />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

**customHook.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const useTextFieldBroken = (id, label, initialValue = "") => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);

  const handleChange = e => {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  };

  const TextField = () => {
    console.log("Rendered the input field");
    return (
      <label htmlFor={id}>
        <h3>{label}</h3>
        <input
          type="text"
          name={id}
          id={id}
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={value}
        />
      </label>
    );
  };

  return [TextField, value, setValue];
};

export default useTextFieldBroken;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/4xj382vj40

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input is losing focus because you're completely re-rendering the tree that creates it on each change.

The good news is that you don't need a hook to do this, just convert your hook into a functional component instead:

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import TextFieldBroken from "./useTextFieldBroken";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [notBrokenValue, notBrokenSetValue] = useState("");

  const notBrokenOnChange = e => {
    notBrokenSetValue(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <label htmlFor="notBroken">
        <h3>Not Broken Input</h3>
        <input
          id="notBroken"
          onChange={notBrokenOnChange}
          value={notBrokenValue}
        />
      </label>
      <TextFieldBroken label="Previously Broken" id="previously-broken" />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

**customHook.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const TextFieldBroken = ({ id, label, initialValue = "" }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);

  const handleChange = e => {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <label htmlFor={id}>
      <h3>{label}</h3>
      <input
        type="text"
        name={id}
        id={id}
        onChange={handleChange}
        value={value}
      />
    </label>
  );
};

export default TextFieldBroken;
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Curious how creating a `FC` instead would solve the problem as the change event would again render `TextFieldBroken` again. Do you mean in the second case `App` does not get rendered due to the change event and only the  `TextFieldBroken` gets rendered due to which the tree is not re created ?

Comment: The difference is that React is smart about the way it compares nodes in the tree, but when you rebuild the node outside of the tree and assign it to a variable like this, then insert it, you're inserting a unique node each time. Take a closer look at your hook function; it defines a new function and assigns it to `TextField` on each run, then returns that new function.